# Capturing the same regular expression over multiple lines

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to capture series of file names that are listed each in a new line, and I have figured out how to capture the file name in the first line, but I haven't figured out how to repeat it on the subsequent lines.

```
# Input
# data/raw/file1
# data/raw/file2

# Output
# data/interim/file1
# data/interim/file2
```

**Current Attempt**

The regular expression I currently have is

`# Input\n(# (.*))`

And my inner capture group properly captures `data/raw/file1`.

**Desired Output**

What I want is to grab all of the files in between `# Input` and `# Output`, so in this example, `data/raw/file1` and `data/raw/file2`.

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of filenames between input and output, or do you care about individual names?

Comment: @chris85 Your solution is grabbing all of the intermediate `#`s in between the file paths, I'd like to just grab the file paths.

Comment: @sln I'm not sure I understand the difference between the two options you provide. I want a list of the filenames on each line in between Input and Output.

Comment: @chris85 Yes this is PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with [**`\G`**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G) magic:

```
(?:^#\s+Input|\G(?!\A))\R*(?!#\s+Output)#\s*(.*)|[\s\S]*
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/jVF4jn/1)

#### Regex breakdown

```
(?:                 # Start of non-capturing group (a)
    ^#\s+Input          # Match a line beginning with `# Input`
    |                   # Or
    \G(?!\A)            # Continue from previous successful match point
)                   # End of NCG (a)
\R*                 # Match any kind of newline characters
(?!#\s+Output)      # Which are not followed by such a line `# Output`
#\s*(.*)            # Start matching a path line and capture path
|                   # If previous patterns didn't match....
[\s\S]*             # Then match everything else up to end to not involve engine a lot
```

PHP code:

```
$re = '~(?:^#\s+Input|\G(?!\A))\R*(?!#\s+Output)#\s*(.*)|[\s\S]*~m';
$str = '# Input
# data/raw/file1
# data/raw/file2

# Output
# data/interim/file1
# data/interim/file2';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
print_r(array_filter($matches[1]));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => data/raw/file1
    [1] => data/raw/file2
)
```

Comment: Thanks I can see that this works, could you perhaps walk through what is going on? This is a lot more complicated than my current familiarity with regular expressions. The Live Demo explains a bit, but I'm not sure how these Lookaheads work.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `s` modifier, `preg_match`, and `preg_split` you can get each result on its own.

```
preg_match('/# Input\n(# (?:.*?))# Output/s', '# Input
# data/raw/file1
# data/raw/file2

# Output
# data/interim/file1
# data/interim/file2', $match);
$matched = preg_split('/# /', $match[1], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($matched);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/dAcRp

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/5tfJGM/1/